# Kruskal-Wallis test on data-augmented sample

Tags: repeated-measures, intraclass-correlation

**summary of problem:**
I have a group of 15 images (15 samples). I have performed data augmentation on these (rotation, inserted noise, etc.): 7 variations of each image (+original img), resulting in a total of 120 (15*8) images.

I want to select a certain region within these 15 images. This is done in 3 algorithms:

- manually:2 independent observers manually pick this region on all 8 variations of each image.
- with a state of the art, semi-automatic algorithm (called MI)
- with my proposed fully automatic algorithm (called HOMOG)

For every chosen region, the coefficient of variance of the selected region is calculated.

Now I want to get the intra- and inter-reader variability for the variance of all regions, for all data-augmented sampled, for all 3 algorithms.

I have several **questions**:

- Does it even make sense to include the fully automated algorithm into this? I expect that it will perform the same on every data-augmented image for each of my 15 samples.
- First I thought about using ICC to asses *intra-reader variability* (variability of the 8 data-augmented variations over the 15 samples). However, this seems to be based on the ANOVA test (https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5440257/). However, ANOVA seems to be based on an assumption of normality. Is the Kruskal-Wallis H-test an appropriate test to assess intra reader variability (as far as I understand this can be seen as the non-normal sibling to ANOVA?)?
- For *inter-reader variability*, I've seen the Bland-Altman plots used in literature, as well as just a two-sided Mann-Whitney test (seeing as this is quantitative data). Would there be any preference between the two for this?

I hope this is clear, any help would be appreciated.

Edit: **Intra-reader variability** is the variability shown by 1 observer, when **evaluating one sample multiple times**. In this case: let's say Image 1 has 8 data-augmented samples. These are all variations on image 1. So if an observer picks the region of interest in these 8 samples, we will effectively have picked 8 regions for 1 image.
E.g.:

- for image 0001, I have the following 8 measures (made by observer 1) of CoV for the region of interest: [0.144, 0.174, 0.486, 0.270, 0.4700, 0.229, 0.328]
- for image 2 I have something similar, etc...

**inter-reader variability** is the variability for the same measurement between observers, eg:

- Observer 1 will observe the following values for image 1: [0.144, 0.174, 0.486, 0.270, 0.47, 0.229, 0.328]
- Observer 2 will observe different values for image 1: [0.138, 0.25667, 0.4220, 0.249, 0.4566, 0.228, 0.3286]

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what mean by "intra- and inter-reader variability". Perhaps, you can clarify a bit more and print some data points from your dataset. Kruskal is a non-parametric test (does not require normality) and is appropriate for independent observations between two+ groups (which is the case in your set up, as I understand).
Kruskal assesses which group has higher observations based on ranking.

Comment: "coefficient of variance" may mean "coefficient of variation".